# Qml Delegate on a separate file

Tags: qt, qml

I have this minimal application that mimics my real one. I have a main qml window with a listview list model and delegate in the same file:

```
Window {
visible: true
width: 640
height: 480
title: qsTr("Hello World")

Component{
    id:deleg
    CheckBox{
        id:chk1
        contentItem: Text {
                id: txt
                anchors.left : parent.indicator.right
                anchors.leftMargin: 10
                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                text: dataname
                color: "blue"
            }}}

ListModel {
    id: mod
    ListElement{
        dataname :'here'
    }
    ListElement{
        dataname : 'there'
    }
}
ListView{
    id: view
    width: 200
    height:100
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.top: parent.top
    model: mod
    delegate: deleg//CheckDelegate {}
}    }
```

main.cpp only load that qml file, like a standard empty Qt Quick application created by Qtcreator.

This will display 2 checkboxes with blue text, all right. Now, If I put the delegate's code in a new qml file, called *ChkDelegate*, and I replace list view delegate with call to ChkDelegate (like in comment above), I face 1 issue, no text is displayed, which I understand, because *dataname* is not resolved. I have tried using link in the brackets, like

```
CheckDelegate { txt : dataname }
```

but I can't reach *txt* property, and *Component* does not allow to put extra property alias in them. How can I solve that?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

First of all I will not use CheckDelegate since it is Default Item, I will change the name to MyCheckDelegate. Going to the problem considers that MyCheckDelegate is a component so it must be generic, besides that when it is overwritten you must encapsulate so you should not use dataname but the same control since the id has a scope, in general you should create a property that gets the information outside and update the internal elements but in this case we will take advantage of the text property of the CheckBox:

**MyCheckDelegate.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

CheckBox{
    id:control
    contentItem: Text {
        id: txt
        anchors.left : parent.indicator.right
        anchors.leftMargin: 10
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        color: "blue"
        text: control.text
    }
}
```

***.qml**

```
// ...
delegate: MyCheckDelegate{
    text: dataname
}
// ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I even was not aware of _CheckDelegate_ existence. In this case, I have the chance to get rid of Component "top" element. But When my delegate is composed of more items ? I won't have choice else than putting a component on top, and no property is allowed on it...

Comment: @claudejoliat You do not have to use Component, you have to use an Item and in it expose the properties through custom aliases or properties: `Item{ id: root; property int h: 10; property alias mytxt: id_txt.text Text {id: id_txt; height: root.h} ... }`

Comment: @claudejoliat - the delegate is always only one root element, how many it nests doesn't really matter in regard with how it is declared. If you only need that delegate in one place, you don't need neither a `Component` nor a separate file, you can put an object there directly, like for example `delegate: Rectangle { width: 20; height: 20 }`. It only makes sense to have separate files if the delegates are big and you don't want to clog up your code, or if you need to also instantiate that object declaratively. Even delegate reuse is possible without having dedicated files.

Answer (score 1):

`CheckBox` already has a `text` property so you can make the binding from the scope that has visibility:

```
  delegate: CheckDelegate { text: dataname }
```

And in your `Text` element, you can bind to that:

```
text: chk1.text
```

Also, it is a very bad idea to name your components the same as stock QML components, because that constitutes a naming collision. You'd have to `import` stock QML modules `as Identifier` in order to resolve it, which is not ideal. And stock QML components seem to take precedence to user defined ones, but even if they didn't, it would still not be ideal. So when you instantiate `CheckDelegate` you are not creating the one you defined, but the one Qt defines.